# difference between module export idioms

Tags: javascript, node.js

*Note: regarding the comment about the similar question I would like to point out that I am not interested in the difference between `module.exports` and `exports`. Rather, my focus in this question is on the difference between exporting a function that - upon calling it - creates an object with the functions we wish to share versus directly assigning these functions as properties of the `exports` object.*

I would like to understand the difference between the following two ways of exporting a module's functions (and hiding local state) in JavaScript:

**way 1**

```
var x = 0;

function get() {return x;}

function set(_x) {x = _x;}

exports.get = get;
exports.set = set;
```

**way 2**

```
module.exports = function () {
    var x = 0;

    function get() {return x;}

    function set(_x) {x = _x;}

    return {get:get, set:set};
};
```

(note that in *way 2* I had to assign to `module.exports`, assigning to `exports` didn't work).

The way the code in *way 1* is used is:

```
var gs = require('./get-set-a.js');

console.log(gs.get());
gs.set(100);
console.log(gs.get());
```

The way the code in *way 2* is used is:

```
var gs = require('./get-set-b.js')();

console.log(gs.get());
gs.set(100);
console.log(gs.get());
```

When running both from the command line, under `node.js` I get identical results.

Is there any difference between *way 1* and *way 2* I should be aware of? Are they perhaps appropriate for different use cases? If not, which is more idiomatic?

Comment: @Andy been there and in similar places; not the same angle - which is why in my question I am only *mentioning* the fact that in the latter case I had to assign to `module.exports` as opposed to `exports` but am not dwelling any further or requiring any clarifications on that.

Comment: @close-voters: this is not a duplicate. Whilst there is confusion here between `module.exports` and `exports`, the actual question here about instances of modules, is not **mentioned** in the 'duplicate' let alone *covered*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second allows you to run multiple "instances" of your module, the first doesn't.

---

**Using the first approach**.

*a.js*

```
var gs = require('./get-set-a.js');

gs.set(100);
console.log(gs.get()); // 100;

require('./b');
```

*b.js*

```
var gs = require('./get-set-a.js');

console.log(gs.get()); // 100;
```

**Using the second approach**

*a.js*

```
var gs = require('./get-set-a.js')();

gs.set(100);
console.log(gs.get()); // 100;

require('./b');
```

*b.js*

```
var gs = require('./get-set-a.js')();

console.log(gs.get()); // 0;
```

---

Just to be perfectly clear, the *multiple instance* thing isn't because you're assigning to `module.exports`, rather than `exports`; it's because your initializer is returning a new closure each time it's called. You could achieve *multiple instances* with just *exports* as such;

*get-set-b.js*

```
exports.create = function () {
    var x = 0;

    function get() {return x;}

    function set(_x) {x = _x;}

    return {get:get, set:set};
};
```

*c.js*

```
var gs = require('./get-set-b.js').create();

console.log(gs.get()); // 0
gs.set(100);
console.log(gs.get()); / 100
```

*d.js*

```
var gs = require('./get-set-b.js').create();

console.log(gs.get()); // 0
gs.set(100);
console.log(gs.get()); // 100
```